# Upgrading to Mule 4.0 on Anypoint Studio 6

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

How we can use Mule Runtime 4.0 on Anypoint Studio 6. I tried to install it via different update sites but it does not see to be available on any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mulesoft forum :

> "You cannot use the Mule 4 runtime in Studio 6 due to the differences
>   in components (compared to Mule 3). So, Studio 6 is exclusively for
>   Mule 3.x, and Studio 7 is exclusively for Mule 4.x."